Excel: XIRR function returns abnormally high value
I'm trying to help a friend calculate the annual rate of return for his boss's brokerage account. The raw data:
Year    Date    Net Transactions    Gains/Losses    Earnings    Overall change
2022    1/1/2022    $3,210.00   $22.24  $0.00   $3,232.24
2022    2/1/2022    $1,710.00   ($101.43)   $0.34   $1,608.91
2022    3/1/2022    $1,710.00   $233.06 $0.00   $1,943.06
2022    4/1/2022    $3,210.00   ($712.61)   $19.87  $2,517.26
2022    5/1/2022    $1,710.00   $56.34  $0.00   $1,766.34
2022    6/1/2022    $1,710.00   ($918.07)   $0.00   $791.93
2022    7/1/2022    $3,210.00   $1,217.34   $51.87  $4,479.21
2022    8/1/2022    $1,710.00   ($736.93)   $0.00   $973.07
2022    9/1/2022    $6,751.21   ($1,678.77) $0.00   $5,072.44
2022    10/1/2022   $10,589.84  $1,982.02   $104.10 $12,675.96
2022    11/1/2022   $11,593.35  $2,209.79   $0.00   $13,803.14
2022    12/1/2022   $11,837.04  ($3,280.64) $242.44 $8,798.84
2023    1/1/2023    $6,501.98   $3,748.00   $0.00   $10,249.98
2023    2/1/2023    $5,001.99   ($1,761.70) $0.00   $3,240.29
2023    3/1/2023    $5,001.99   $2,810.93   $0.00   $7,812.92
2023    4/1/2023    $6,501.99   $953.41 $296.88 $7,752.28
2023    5/1/2023    $5,001.98   $399.27 $0.00   $5,401.25
2023    6/1/2023    $5,001.99   $6,151.51   $0.00   $11,153.50
2023    7/1/2023    $6,502.00   $2,981.85   $401.08 $9,884.93
2023    8/1/2023    $5,001.99   ($1,779.56) $0.00   $3,222.43
2023    9/1/2023    $5,001.98   ($5,682.92) $0.00   ($680.94)
2023    10/1/2023   $6,501.99   ($2,963.60) $433.01 $3,971.40
2023    11/1/2023   $5,001.99   $11,027.97  $0.00   $16,029.96
2023    12/1/2023   $4,977.99   $5,566.93   $609.85 $11,154.77
2024    1/1/2024    $6,752.00   $2,463.76   $0.00   $9,215.76
2024    2/1/2024    $82,074.39  $9,826.36   $0.00   $91,900.75
2024    3/1/2024    $77,311.36  $9,830.31   $0.00   $87,141.67
2024    4/1/2024    $6,751.99   ($14,814.89)    $1,012.96   ($7,049.94)
2024    5/1/2024    $5,252.00   $16,297.67  $0.00   $21,549.67
2024    6/1/2024    $5,251.99   $12,545.60  $0.00   $17,797.59
2024    7/1/2024    $6,751.99   $3,232.06   $1,207.32   $11,191.37
2024    8/1/2024    $5,252.00   $9,296.70   $0.00   $14,548.70

So I'm trying to use the XIRR function and take every net transaction as negative cash flow and add the final balance as positive cash flow. Then I use XIRR() over both of these columns:
Date    Cash flow
1/1/2022    -3210.00
2/1/2022    -1710.00
3/1/2022    -1710.00
4/1/2022    -3210.00
5/1/2022    -1710.00
6/1/2022    -1710.00
7/1/2022    -3210.00
8/1/2022    -1710.00
9/1/2022    -6751.21
10/1/2022   -10589.84
11/1/2022   -11593.35
12/1/2022   -11837.04
1/1/2023    -6501.98
2/1/2023    -5001.99
3/1/2023    -5001.99
4/1/2023    -6501.99
5/1/2023    -5001.98
6/1/2023    -5001.99
7/1/2023    -6502.00
8/1/2023    -5001.99
9/1/2023    -5001.98
10/1/2023   -6501.99
11/1/2023   -5001.99
12/1/2023   -4977.99
1/1/2024    -6752.00
2/1/2024    -82074.39
3/1/2024    -77311.36
4/1/2024    -6751.99
5/1/2024    -5252.00
6/1/2024    -5251.99
7/1/2024    -6751.99
8/1/2024    -5252.00
8/30/2024   393150.74
XIRR(J2:J34,I2:I34,0.07)    23.51%

That returns 0.2351 which I believe corresponds to 23.51% ARR but that seems ludicrous. The Date column is formatted as a Date and the Cash flow entries are formatted as a Number. I've checked the data and besides his larger than usual deposits in 2024 I don't see anomalies or a duplicate entry. It's been a while since I used Excel and I haven't used XIRR before; where have I gone wrong? I think 23% is roughly the return over the lifetime of the account so either I'm misusing XIRR or I've misunderstood what it does.

Did you enter an appropriate Guess for your values? Also, please edit your question to include your data as text which can be copy/pasted. Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?

Thanks Ross! I've updated the question to include the data as text and removed the images

At first glance, it does not appear as if you have the relevant information. Your initial entry should be the balance in the account at the start of the period (as a negative number) followed by a list of deposits or withdrawals to/from that account (deposits are negative and withdrawals positive) and ending with the final account balance (a positive number).  It appears to me that you don't have a starting balance, and I'm not sure of the relevance of the "net transaction" numbers unless they represent actual withdrawals from the account.

This account was opened at the start of 2022 so the starting balance was 0. Net transactions are mislabeled; they are deposits to the account. That's why I made the second list with all of those as a negative number and relabeled them "Cash flow"

If those are deposits to the account, then the calculation appears to be correct. And since about ½ the funds were deposited during the six months prior to the final evaluation date, it kind of makes sense.

I guess I should ask this guy for investment advice haha. Thanks!
